# Are there any GUI "Apache POI" like application?

Tags: database, apache-poi, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a application that can create XLS templates with data I'll export from a Database.

I need to customize the order data is inserted into de XLS document, and create some derivative columns as well.

Comment: Maybe JasperReports is something for you...

Comment: @kiwiwings Thanks sir! Submit it as an answer, it fits very well.

Comment: [Vaardin Spreadsheet](https://vaadin.com/spreadsheet) may work for you too - their demo spreadsheet app might be almost close enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question might be closed because it is [opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), my usual candidates for such a task are [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) or [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/).